# Disabling external monitor with xrandr also disables laptop screen

Tags: display, xrandr

When an external monitor is connected, xrandr shows me two displays: `eDP1` (laptop screen) and `DP1` (external monitor).

I can enable the external monitor just fine, but if I unplug the external monitor, or disable it with `xrandr --output DP1 --off`, the laptop screen goes blank too (though still backlit). I believe I can still switch to a tty on the laptop screen.

Any ideas how to keep my laptop screen running after disabling/disconnecting the external monitor?

If it matters, I'm using i3.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm using i3" -- what is "i3"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using i3 windowing manager but what could be happening here is external monitor is the primary monitor and laptop display mirrors it. Either way create this bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output DP1 --off
xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --primary
```

Mark the script as executable: `chmod a+x /path/to/scriptname`

Then call the script with `/path/to/scriptname`

Replace `eDP1` with your laptop monitor name discovered using:

```bash
xrandr | grep " connected"
```